# Как обработать push android

Tags: android, уведомления, firebase, push-уведомления

Как сделать так, чтобы когда приложение в бэкгранде, push уведомление отправлялось не сразу в `notification center`, а обрабатывалось приложением методом `onMessageReceived`? Пуш сделано на `firebase`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Отправляйте data-сообщения (без объекта Notification)

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> - Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
> - Data messages, which are handled by the client app.
>
> Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages
> have only custom key-value pairs.
>
> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you want to process the messages on your client app.

[About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: А как можно осуществить отправку data сообщений?

Comment: Из документации _"Use your app server and FCM server API: Set the data key only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible."_, например:

`{
  "to": "device_token",
  "data": {
    "key": "value"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

убрать метод `super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);`

Answer (score 1):

Я использую замечательную библиотеку [RxFcm](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/RxFcm), в ней есть классы которые помогут сделать то что вам нужно без особого труда